# "Past instances in which I professed to like you were fraudulent"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the joke with the sentence "Past instances in which I professed to like you were fraudulent"

> Homer: Ned Flanders, I mock your value system. You also appear foolish
>   to the eyes of others.
>
> Flanders: Well howdy, Homer! [partition slides up] Ooh, thanks for
>   dropping by!
>
> Dr. Foster: Hmm. He's not responding. [into microphone] Proceed to
>   level 2 antagonism. [slides down partition]
>
> Homer: **Past instances in which I professed to like you were
>   fraudulent.**
>
> Flanders: Oh, well, I'll just have to try harder. Heh heh. [partition
>   slides up] Ooh! Thanks for dropping by!
>
> Dr. Foster: Ah, he's still repressing. [into microphone] Maximum
>   hostility factor. [slide down partition]
>
> Homer: I engaged in intercourse with your spouse or significant other.
>   Now that's psychiatry! Eh? Eh?

http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Hurricane_Neddy/Quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is a very stilted way of saying "I was lying when I told you that I liked you". The humor comes from the context though. If I remember this episode correctly, Homer is reading these monotonously from a cue card (except for his own comment:"Now that's psychiatry! Eh?") in an attempt to upset Ned.

The joke is that the psychiatrist are having Homer say hurtful/inflammatory things, but with very clinical and courteous phrasing.

Edit: I should mention that Ned's responses also add to the joke. Not only is Ned not noticing how bizarrely Homer is phrasing his insults, he's responding with an absurd level of friendliness and politeness.